# When can a BluetoothLE operation prompt for consent on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I developed a command-line program that connects to a BLE device (a motion sensor), subscribes to motion notifications, then prints the coordinates to stdout around 60 times per second. The data is consumed by a legacy Adobe AIR desktop application (which handles running of my "driver" program).

I have used Microsoft's Bluetooth Low Energy code samples as a reference.
I've found the following in one of the code samples:

```
// BT_Code: BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync must be called from a UI thread because it may prompt for consent.
bluetoothLeDevice = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(SampleState::SelectedBleDeviceId);
```

Those samples are UWP apps, but my program is C++/WinRT console program, and naturally has no UI thread. So I am guessing that in case of consent prompt it will just fail.

I've finished writing the program and it's working, but this comment got me worried about some situation where this consent prompt topic will become an issue. Or perhaps it can work now, and break with some future Windows update if they introduce more widespread consent dialogs.

So far I found that pairing a device requires consent ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices)). My device doesn't require pairing.

I would like to know if there's a well-defined list of cases when a Bluetooth LE consent prompt might be required?

Comment: If your device do not need to pair or you pair with device from your code you do not need to worry about UI thread. By my experience even if device needs to be paired and Windows shows prompt it does not matter if your code runs not in UI thread in classic (non UWP) app.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for your reply. Sounds like I should be golden, then? My program uses the Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT) template, provided by the C++/WinRT Visual Studio Extension (VSIX). I am bit confused whether or not this make it a UWP app or not. Sounds like it's not, but for example this [Microsoft doc on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started) is in the UWP section of the docs.

Comment: It does not looks like UWP app. It is simple native (desktop) console app. At least at my first view.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks! Then I guess I shouldn't worry about it

Comment: I think yes, You shouldn't. At least we do not in our library (Bluetooth Framework) and all works without any problem.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I also asked this question in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/237313/ble-when-can-a-bluetoothle-operation-prompt-for-co.html). I got this reply from them: "The requirement that BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync must be called from a UI thread in the official sample is specifically for UWP app. This means there is no need to execute any of the Bluetooth methods on a UI thread in your console app."

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Would you like to post your comments as an answer, so that I can accept it? I appreciate your help.